# Which Google GWT product uses UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to know which product of google written in GWT uses UiBinder. This would allow me to highlight the use case of UiBinder for our team/management.

I am aware of following list of [Google Products that use GWT](https://plus.google.com/+RayCromwell/posts/ivVepvxCu3g). ***Which one uses UiBinder?***

```
AdWords - http://google.com/adwords
AdSense - http://google.com/adsense
Flights - http://flights.google.com
Hotel Finder - http://www.google.com/hotelfinder
Offers - https://www.google.com/offers
Wallet - http://wallet.google.com
The New Blogger - http://www.blogger.com/
Chrome Webstore - https://chrome.google.com/webstore (Closure, but embeds GWT checkout code)
Product Search - http://www.google.com/prdhp?hl=en&tab=mf
Public Data - http://www.google.com/publicdata/home
New Google Groups - http://groups.google.com
Orkut - http://www.orkut.com
Google Health (discontinued)
Google Wave (discontinued)
PlayN (basis of Angry Birds)
Google Takeout - https://www.google.com/takeout/#custom
Google Pagespeed - https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/
Google WebFonts - http://www.google.com/webfonts
Google Tables - https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=2049253
Google Merchants - http://www.google.com/merchants
```

Comment: I have been away from GWT for too long, but this begs a question. Since UiBinder can do everything that that you can do through code and does not restrict you in any way, what is the hesitation? UiBinder markup is more soothing to the eye than the UI code written in Java. Besides, UI/UX designers who cannot stand java code will appreciate the simplicity of uiBinder markup. This is for you to prototype and vetting by google coders will not leave you in any better position.

Comment: Indeed it makes it simple to build UI. That would also raise the query from management as to which google gwt product uses it :)

Comment: Tell them tell them they are not google and google does not do CRUD apps. UiBinder does not bring in as much value for a dashboard type app as it does for CRUD.

Comment: Can you tell me where you got this list ? or any proof for that ?

Comment: Its fascinating that you put a comment on this question after getting it closed a year ago!!!!! The above list is published across some gwt google groups discussion and GWT Google+ discussion by Google Dev RAY Cromwell -> https://plus.google.com/+RayCromwell/posts/ivVepvxCu3g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nearly impossible to tell with certainty, because UiBinder generates code that you could have written by hand, but if you see large chunks of HTML in the script then there are good chances they come from an `HTMLPanel` in a UiBinder template or a `UiRenderer`; particularly if the string ends with `<span id='` or starts with `'></span>` (but it could also simply come from a `SafeHtmlTemplates` or a hand-coded `HTMLPanel` or `setInnerHTML` call.

Comment: Is there any way any google engineer can shed light on this? Should i cross post this on gwt google groups since this is closed here?

Comment: No harm in trying, but I must say I can't see what it'll buy you. `RenderablePanel` was added by Orkut engineers and it plays best with UiBinder so Orkut must be using UiBinder, now "so what?"

Comment: That's a start. Orkut most probably uses UiBinder.